# how to use firebase https trigger functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a token generator using firebase cloud functions and I wanted to use an https trigger to create the token, however I need to include data within the call to the url. I know it is possible but I don't necessarily know how to do it.

I need this so I can set values for certain variables in my function.

So the final url might look something like this in pseudo code:

https://tokengen/identity=/room=

here, identity and room are the two values I want to include for the variales for when calling the function.

so to reiterate,

I know you can request data using:
`exports.token = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {`

but how do I include data along with the https call to include as variables. An example would be greatly appreciated. As would any answers, suggestions, or references.

**EDIT:**

here's the updated code,

```
exports.tokenGenerator = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
const { identity, roomName } = request.query;

const AccessToken = require('twilio').jwt.AccessToken;
const VideoGrant = AccessToken.VideoGrant;

const twilioAccountSid = '1xxxxxxxxxx';
const twilioApiKey = '1xxxxxxxxxx';
const twilioApiSecret = '1xxxxxxxxxx';



function generateToken(identity, roomName) {
  const videoGrant = new VideoGrant({
room: roomName
});

  const token = new AccessToken(twilioAccountSid, twilioApiKey, twilioApiSecret);
  token.addGrant(videoGrant);
  token.identity = identity;

  return token.toJwt();

}

  response.send(token.toJwt());

});
```

when I use the url it returns `Error: could not handle the request`

Comment: Check out this example here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron It shows an example of how to include and access a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
https://yourFB.cloudfunctions.net/token?identity=12&room=12
```

and you can use it like -

```
exports.token = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const { identity, room } = request.query;
    ...
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi I'm still having a bit of trouble. I'm getting the error could not handle request. Would you mind reviewing the code? I think it has to do with handling the response. I will include the code in the question as an edit.

Comment: hey, sorry about the delay, can you show me your full `url`, another thing to note is you're using `twilio` which is external service and you have to be on paid firebase account

Comment: What do you mean by "be on paid firebase account" do you need a paid account to use cloud functions? Also here is the url https://us-central1-videochattest-dbd0d.cloudfunctions.net/tokenGenerator?identity=12&room=12

Comment: could you go to the `logs` and check what it's printing? if you use google api then it's free. If you use external api then you have to be on paid account. Shall we check the logs first and confirm if that's the case

Comment: Oh okay I see the error in the log. It was saying exactly that. Thank you.

Comment: glad i could help.